# Letting users "GRANT SELECT" without making them admins or giving them CONTROL permission

Tags: permissions, ssms, database-administration

Background info:
I administrate a database in SSMS. I am the only administrator. I have users creating tables, and then they want to grant select permissions on those tables, to other users. But they are not allowed to do it because they are not administrators or have CONTROL permission on the schema.

Question:
How can I as an SSMS database administrator let users grant SELECT on tables they create to other users, without making them admins or giving them CONTROL permissions?

Comment: Although I answered, this is really a question for suited for one of our sister sites, like https://superuser.com or https://dba.stackexchange.com (and I've voted to nudge it over there). I'll leave the answer there on the off-chance it gets migrated rather than closed and deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply get users to create a table in their own schema along the lines of (SSMS syntax may be different, this is just meant to be illustrative):

```
create table select_access (
    table_name varchar[50],
    user_name varchar[50],
    is_active varchar
)
```

Then have an admin job run periodically (every five or ten minutes, for example) and, for every applicable user, examine the entries in that table.

If there's an entry for a table *not* currently having the permission (with `is_active` set to `Y`), grant the permission. If there's an entry for a table currently *having* the permission (with `is_active` set to `N`), remove the permission.

That way, they have full control over select permissions on their tables without getting you involved.

To share a table, they just create it, add entries to `select_access` for each user they want to share it with, then wait for your job to run.

To disable, they just set the `is_active` field to `N` for the users they want to revoke access for and, again, wait for your job to run.

The use of `is_active` is just to make your life easier, as your only necessary source of information is just that table.

You *could* make it smarter by just letting them delete the row for the given user/table but then you'd have to process the table *and* all their tables that may have access granted but no longer have an entry in `select_access`.

Just make sure any table they grant permissions to is a table in *their* schema, not one of the system tables :-)